# Devise user sign_up with params of a previous custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have the following problem in my app: I have a model called Budget and I want new users of my app to be able to create Budget objets within their first seconds in the app. So I want to let them fill the form, then be redirected to Devise's sign up page (action) and then create the user and the Budget object he declared before sign up.

How can I do that? I'm pretty sure I'll have to customize the `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` controller. What else? How can I pass the parameters from my `BudgetsController#create` action to my `Users::RegistrationsController#create` action?

Comment: You can use javascript to implement this

Comment: why not use `redirect_to new_user_registration_path(params: params_what_you_need)`?